# Chaining Webrick Proxies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, proxy

I have been trying to test the chaining of Webrick proxies, and I am having some trouble.

Each proxy works fine on its own from 127.0.0.1:port (when :ProxyURI is commented out for proxy_2), but I am getting the error:

```
ERROR unsupported method `GET'.
```

from proxy_2 output (httpproxy.rb) when I try chaining them.

To clarify, when I chain them I am using 127.0.0.1:8086 as my access point from another application.

Looking at the logs for proxy_1, it appears that it is not receiving any requests.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
require 'webrick'
require 'webrick/httpproxy'

port_1 = 8085
port_2 = 8086

proxy_1 = 
  WEBrick::HTTPProxyServer.new(
    :Port          => port_1,
    :ServerType    => Thread,
    :Logger        => WEBrick::Log.new("./logs/#{port_1}.out"),
    :ServerName => "future_authentication_proxy"
  )
proxy_1.start

proxy_2 = 
  WEBrick::HTTPProxyServer.new(
    :Port          => port_2,
    :ProxyURI => '127.0.0.1:'+port_1.to_s
  )
trap("INT"){
  proxy_1.shutdown
  proxy_2.shutdown
}
proxy_2.start
```

Comment: I think you'll have better luck running them as separate processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed wrong ProxyURI option, it should be something like:

```
:ProxyURI => URI.parse("http://#{host_1_ip}:#{port_1}/")
```